# How to change name and author values in package.json of Openshift node.js application?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, git, openshift

I am new to node.js and PaaS like Openshift as well. So I have this question, how do I change the generated values of Openshift to the package.json without errors? Because everytime I change it, git shows "npm ERR! Error: Invalid Name: "Sample App". Sorry if this was a really basic question but I cannot find any answer anywhere yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From npm's [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

> New packages must not have uppercase letters in the name.
>
> The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.

Conclusion:

Don't use uppercase letters, nor spaces.

Comment: my goodness. Such stupidity of me. Thank you! The  problem was not actually with the capitalization but with the space. It went fine after that.

Comment: The problem with the capitalization will only be there if you plan to upload to npm, so better don't use it at all... :)  @dtem052996

Comment: I see. Thanks for the early warning!